# Are all PEX-A pipes from one brand to the next built to the same standards?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I've read that Uponor PEX-A has what's called "undulations" on the interior which causes imminent failure when exposed to chlorine and a current class action lawsuit claiming the patented process they use to apply colorant to the exterior causes micro cracks to occur where it's expanded on the ends. Does all PEX-A have these characteristics?

I need to repipe my home and I'm not sure which PEX-A product to use. I just want to make sure whatever I use will last the longest.

Comment: Will you be using chlorine in the pipes? if not, why is that relevant?

Comment: Afaik "city water" is much more likely to have been treated with chloramine than chlorine. Chloramine is apparently much less volatile than chlorine, so *might* not have the same effect on PEX ...

Comment: PEX has not existed for long enough to answer this question with authority.   It has been around for about 50 or 55 years, but only used *commonly* for water supply for the last 20 or 30 years.  If it was all going to fail in 20 years we'd be hearing about it now.  If it was all going to fail in 40 years, it's not time yet.     Note, copper can fail quickly too if installed incorrectly or with manufacturing defects.  Most of the copper pipes in my house are older than most of the PEX in the world but I've had plenty of failures.  **Ask again in 50 years.**